# There is no implicit reference conversion from "Derive Type" to "Base type" in Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Here is the code

```
 public interface IEntity<T>  
   {
       T Id { get; set; }
   }


public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>       
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }

 public class Country : Entity<int>
    {
...
    }

 public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity<Type>
    {
    }

 public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
       where T : Entity<Type>
    {
    }

 public class CountryRepository : Repository<Country>
{
}
```

I am getting following error:

> The type 'Model.Country' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Repository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Country' to 'Entity<System.Type>'.

How can I map derived type to base type as generic parameter?

**Edit:**

I got my solution here by creating one more baseclass and use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx

Moderator can delete this question

Comment: `Type` is a framework class. Use another name.

Comment: Your title is misleading.

Comment: @Rawling What is misleading...this is the error I am getting.

Comment: Because `Country` is not derived from `Entity<System.Type>`, it's derived from `Entity<int>`.

Comment: what should be there? I should be able to pass any datatype int, short, long ..etc. I tried with Entity<object> but got same error.

Comment: @WebWorld what was the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You are violating your generic constraint:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
   where T : Entity<Type> // <= here
```

and

```
public class Country : Entity<int>
```

`Entity<int>` is not `Entity<Type>`.

If you want to allow "any type" you can do this via a common base class:

```
public abstract class Entity { }
public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity, IEntity<T>       
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
   where T : Entity
{
}
```

Comment: what should be there? I should be able to pass any datatype int, short, long ..etc. I tried with Entity<object> but got same error.

Comment: @WebWorld: Even if you already found it out on your own I added it to my answer for others to see. If this is not how you did it maybe "self-answer" the question with your solution...